# Converting time format using Read_sql method

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a sql table containing time format using Pandas' `read_sql` but it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot cast unit %H:%M:%s
```

My piece of code:

```
data = pd.read_sql('select curtime() as time1 from dual',mysql_con,parse_dates={'time1':'%H:%M:%s'})
```